# How to test POST method using Mockito

Tags: java, web-services, unit-testing, mockito

HI have the following test and I cannot make it work:

```
protected HttpClient mHttpClientMock;
protected HttpPost mHttpPostMock;
protected HttpResponse mHttpResponseMock;
protected StatusLine mStatusLineMock;
protected HttpEntity mHttpEntityMock;
protected ContentResolver mResolver;

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    // Create mocks.
    mHttpPostMock = Mockito.mock(HttpPost.class);
    mHttpClientMock = Mockito.mock(HttpClient.class);
    mHttpResponseMock = Mockito.mock(HttpResponse.class);
    mStatusLineMock = Mockito.mock(StatusLine.class);
    mHttpEntityMock = Mockito.mock(HttpEntity.class);

    prepareMocks();

    // Obtain Content Resolver.
    mResolver = getContext().getContentResolver();
}


protected void prepareMocks() throws IOException {
    // Create mocked response.
    // Define expected calls.
    Mockito.when(mHttpClientMock.execute(Mockito.isA(HttpPost.class)));
//Mockito.when(mHttpResponseMock.getStatusLine()).thenReturn(mStatusLineMock);
//  Mockito.when(mStatusLineMock.getStatusCode()).thenReturn(HttpStatus.SC_OK);
//  Mockito.when(mHttpResponseMock.getEntity()).thenReturn(mHttpEntityMock);
    Mockito.when(mHttpClientMock.execute(Mockito.mock(Markup.class)));
 //  Mockito.when(mHttpEntityMock.writeTo(Mockito.mock(Markup.class));
}
```

How do I prepare my (Markup.class) Post, so I can test it later on.

Thank you very much
Best Regards.

Comment: What problem are you having?  You should look at the documentation of how to use `when`

Comment: I'm not sure where and how I have to mock markup post

Comment: there's no test in the code above -- just a setup method calling another method that prepares mocks.  Since I do not see a test it is hard to be sure, but my guess is that you are trying to mock way too much also.  Only use a mock if you need to.

Comment: @KevinWelker I just need to know who set mockito

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was it!!!

```
        InputStream jsonResponse = createJsonResponse();
    // Define expected calls.
    Mockito.when(mHttpClientMock.execute(Mockito.isA(HttpPost.class))).thenReturn(mHttpResponseMock);
    Mockito.when(mHttpResponseMock.getStatusLine()).thenReturn(mStatusLineMock);
    Mockito.when(mStatusLineMock.getStatusCode()).thenReturn(HttpStatus.SC_OK);
    Mockito.when(mHttpResponseMock.getEntity()).thenReturn(mHttpEntityMock);
    Mockito.when(mHttpEntityMock.getContent()).thenReturn(jsonResponse);
```

Answer (score 0):

Testing web service with Mockito is doable, but if you want to test dynamic behaviour it is much better to use [RestAssured](https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/) testing framework. It is mostly designed to test REST web services, but can be also used to test "normal" HTTP form posts.

If you mock everything with Mockito, you would test mostly your mocks, not a real behaviour.

Testing with Mockito would mean that you create mock HTTP request and then pass it to some method which consumes that request. The you can create some assertions that would check if method parsed request properly and gave correct outcome.